# How to run single spec in a single thread?

Tags: multithreading, rspec

My specs:

```
it "has empty thread" do
  Thread.current[:foo].should be_nil
  Thread.current[:foo] = "bar"
end

it "has empty thread" do
  Thread.current[:foo].should be_nil
end
```

Second spec fails because thread was changed by previous spec.
How can I run specs in different threads or 'nullify' thread's keys before each spec or something else to pass second spec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the `Thread` in the spec ; don't' forget to `join` it to get the results of the `should`'s from the thread re-evaluated:

```
it "has empty thread" do
    Thread.new {
        Thread.current[:foo].should be_nil
        Thread.current[:foo] = "bar"
    }.join
end

it "has empty thread" do
    Thread.new {
        Thread.current[:foo].should be_nil
    }.join
end
```